# How to combine two arrays by deep key?

Tags: php, arrays, merge, array-merge, array-column

I want to combine two arrays using specified deep subarray values.

I have two different arrays with different structures and I want to combine them so that if the "primary keys" match then add second array's values to the first array, if not then create array with array 2's value.

Primary key in first array is `[created_by]` and in second array it's `[upgrade_by]`

Array1 is:

```
Array(      
        [0] => Array(
                [Customer] => Array(
                        [created_by] => 5
                        [amount] => 199
                        [name] => First Cux
                )
        )
        [1] => Array(
                [Customer] => Array(
                        [created_by] => 1
                        [amount] => 199
                        [name] => Last Cux
                )
        )
)
```

Array 2 is

```
Array(
        [0] => Array(
                [0] => Array(
                        [refund_amount] => 100
                )
                [Historycustomer] => Array(
                        [upgrade_by] => 1
                        [company] => First Company
                )
        )
        [1] => Array(
                [0] => Array(
                        [refund_amount] => 250
                )
                [Historycustomer] => Array(
                        [upgrade_by] => 3
                        [company] => Last Company
                )
        )
)
```

I need result like this:

```
Array(      
        [0] => Array(
                [Customer] => Array(
                        [created_by] => 5
                        [amount] => 199
                        [name] => First Cux
                )
        )
        [1] => Array(
                [Customer] => Array(
                        [created_by] => 1
                        [amount] => 199
                        [refund_mount]=>100
                        [name] => Last Cux
                        [company] => First Company
                )
        )
        [2] => Array(
                [Customer] => Array(
                        [created_by] => 3
                        [refund_mount]=>250
                        [company] => Last Company
                )
        )
)
```

Primary key in first array is `[created_by]` and in second array it's `[upgrade_by]`

Comment: Yes,  I'm still looking for this solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach will use input array `$a` as the result array.  `foreach()` will loop through the subarrays of `$b`.  `$index` (the key of the subarray in `$a` which holds the `upgrade_by` value in its `created_by` value) is found by:

1. Isolating the deepest subarrays in `$a`'s `Customer` "columns" using `array_column()` -- these are the 3-element arrays.
2. `array_column()` is used again to isolate the `created_by` values within these subarrays.
3. `array_search()` hunts for the specified number in the new isolated array and if it exists, returns its index.

When the index is found, `$b`'s values are merged with `$a`'s values using the given index and the `upgrade_by` element is omitted.

When the index is not found, `upgrade_by` is renamed `created_by` and the elements are added to `$a` as a new customer subarray.

Code: ([Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0db84be96b03e80df64f2480373f01d79231f213))

```
$a=[
    ['Customer'=>['created_by'=>5,'amount'=>199,'name'=>'First Cux']],
    ['Customer'=>['created_by'=>1,'amount'=>199,'name'=>'Last Cux']]
];
$b=[
    [['refund_amount'=>100],'Historycustomer'=>['upgrade_by'=>1,'company'=>'First Company']],
    [['refund_amount'=>250],'Historycustomer'=>['upgrade_by'=>3,'company'=>'Last Company']]
];
$created_by_indexes=array_column(array_column($a,'Customer'),'created_by');
foreach($b as $b1){
    $index=array_search($b1['Historycustomer']['upgrade_by'],$created_by_indexes);
    if($index!==false){
        $a[$index]['Customer']+=['refund_amount'=>$b1[0]['refund_amount'],'company'=>$b1['Historycustomer']['company']];
    }else{
        $a[]=['Customer'=>['created_by'=>$b1['Historycustomer']['upgrade_by'],'refund_amount'=>$b1[0]['refund_amount'],'company'=>$b1['Historycustomer']['company']]];
    }
}
var_export($a);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Customer' => 
    array (
      'created_by' => 5,
      'amount' => 199,
      'name' => 'First Cux',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Customer' => 
    array (
      'created_by' => 1,
      'amount' => 199,
      'name' => 'Last Cux',
      'refund_amount' => 100,
      'company' => 'First Company',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Customer' => 
    array (
      'created_by' => 3,
      'refund_amount' => 250,
      'company' => 'Last Company',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: It's working fine. I have three similar arrays which need to merge. In that conditions I first merge the two array with this code help and again merge the mergedarray with third array. Its working fine but code is very heavy. Becuase any of or all of array could be empty and I had to run multiple if else conditions. :)

Comment: @SAHAR Just so you know, I've refined my code.  Please implement my small change of `$created_by_indexes` before the loop.  While the old version was "working fine", I prefer to post optimized/refined methods so that future readers can see best practices.